# Kubernetes fails to deploy valid container image

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I have a docker image containing an NodeJS app. The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "./start.sh" ]
```

The start.sh script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
echo "Starting application"
npm start
```

I'm able to launch and test the image manually:

```
$ gcloud docker -- run -it --rm my-container
...
Starting application
...
> node index.js
...
```

The same container is used by a kubernetes deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: my-container
...
```

The container starts, the `start.sh` script is correctly executed but it terminates and the container goes into a `CrashLoopBackOff` loop.

After inspecting the pod manually:

```
kubectl exec -ti my-pod -- bash
I have no name!@my-pod:/app# cat /etc/passwd
... empty response
```

-> ***It appears that somehow there are no system users on the container, which makes most commands (like `npm`) fail silently and terminate the container***

I have also tried, without success:

- deleting the pod
- deleting and re-creating the deployment
- running the `node` image with the `node` user -> `unable to find user node: no matching entries in passwd file`

Last note: I actually have many deployments (using the same template with just a different name) which are running fine with an image that was built a few days ago ***with the same source code***.

For some deployments, it actually worked after manually deleting the pod and letting kubernetes recreate it.

Any ideas?

***Edit 18/01/2018*** I have tried rebuilding an image with the same source code that old working images use, without success. I have also tried a simpler Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
USER node
```

But I still get an error related to the fact that no users seem to be there:

```
Error response from daemon: {"message":"linux spec user: unable to find user node: no matching entries in passwd file"}
```

I have checked with the docker-node guys, the image hasn't changed recently. Could it be related to kubernetes changes? Keep it mind that my images ***do run*** when I run them manually with the docker command.

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: @DavidSteiman The pod logs display `Starting application` but nothing happens next as the pod terminates. As I explained, when looking directly in the container I see that there are no system users, thus commands like `npm start` or `node --version` have no effect at all (not even an error on the output).

Comment: what about starting the script directly, as mentioned here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-your-nodejs-application

Comment: I need to run some logic before the `npm start` so I can't use the `CMD` instruction directly, if that's what your suggesting

Comment: why don't implementing that logic inside a npm task?

Comment: @DavidSteiman Actually with `CMD ["npm", "start"]` I get `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as @heckj pointed out, it was a Docker issue on my kubernetes cluster. I updated the cluster from `1.6.13-gke.1` to `v1.7.12-gke.0` and the pods worked fine again. I'm not sure what Docker version was used since there's [another kubernetes bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54039) that is preventing me from seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but didn't get it to fail in anything like the same fashion. I made a [dummy express app](https://github.com/heckj/dummyexpress) and stuck it on github that matches your example above, and then invoked it into a local minikube instance I had. The base image size is reasonably large, but it started up just fine.

I had to interpret what was happening within `npm start` for your example since you didn't specify, but you can see my [package.json](https://github.com/heckj/dummyexpress/blob/master/package.json#L8), which I suspect is pretty close to what you're doing based on the description.

When I fire this up:

```
git clone https://github.com/heckj/dummyexpress
cd dummyexpress
kubectl apply -f deploy/
```

The I got a running instance right off the bat:

```
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dummynodeapp-7788b95497-tkw2s   1/1       Running   0          1d
```

And the logs show pretty much what you'd expect:

```
**kubectl log dummynodeapp-7788b95497-tkw2s**
W0117 19:41:00.986498   20648 cmd.go:353] log is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use logs instead.
Starting application

> blah@1.0.0 start /app
> node index.js

Example app listening on port 3000!
```

My guess is that you've got something going awry within your `npm start` execution, so I'd recommend fiddling with that aspect of your deployment and see if you can't resolve it that way.

Comment: Hi @heckj, thanks for taking the time. See my edited question, I still have the problem without the script, and it doesn't seem related to my app source code.

Comment: I created a deployment using your exact `dummynodeapp.yaml` and I am still getting `CrashLoopBackOff` with `Starting application` as the only logs!

Comment: Digging on the specific error you're seeing, it matches [a closed moby bug - #22323](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22323), but clearly maps this to a docker problem. I suspect something is seriously messed up on the docker in your your kubernetes cluster based on this. You've verified docker runs locally, but have you tried the same thing on docker on the bare-node that's in your cluster?